# Intel Fortran compiling: unresolved warning

Tags: matlab, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to compile a complicated program that merges Matlab and Fortran and I get the errors

```
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved runpoissonsolver_
        Referenced in /tmp/ipo_ifort73gcto.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved setuppoissonsolver_
        Referenced in /tmp/ipo_ifort73gcto.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved utFree
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libeng.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved matCreateMATFile
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libeng.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved utCalloc
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libeng.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved matGetNextVariable
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libeng.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved matClose
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libeng.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved utF2cstr
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libeng.so
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved matPutNextVariable
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libeng.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved ucnv_getNextUChar_52
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN5boost6detail25get_once_per_thread_epochEv
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN2fl4i18n8MwLocale6globalEv
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN6MATLAB14getReshapeDims10unknownDimC1Ev
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTVN2fl6except6detail14bad_alloc_impl8internalE
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved utSetLastWarningMsg
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZN6MATLAB15legacy_two_part11noformat_mxC1Ev
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved enc_to_utf16_n
        Referenced in /afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so
....
....
....
```

This continues for several hundred more lines of errors. Here are the commands I use to compile.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set FC=ifort

module switch matlab matlab/8.5

set matlabroot=/afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5

set PATH = ($PATH "$matlabroot/bin/glnxa64/")
set PATH = ($PATH "$matlabroot/bin")

set LD_LIBRARY_PATH = ( $LD_LIBRARY_PATH "$matlabroot/bin/glnxa64/")
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH = ( $LD_LIBRARY_PATH "$matlabroot/sys/os/glnxa64/")

${FC} Constants.f90 PRNG.f90 NonElementaryFunctions.f90 Calculus.f90 InputFile.f90 ElectrodeGeometry.f90 ExtraFunctions.f90 CustomClasses.f90 GlobalVars.f90 Transformations.f90 StatisticalDistribution.f90 StatisticalMechanics.f90 PoissonSolver.f90 ParticleInCell.f90 MonteCarloCollision.f90 Emission.f90 ElectricalSystem.f90 NDPIC1D.f90 -I${matlabroot}/extern/include/ -L${matlabroot}/bin/glnxa64/ -leng -lmx -fpp -i8 -autodouble -check bounds -check pointers -check uninit -heap-arrays -o FEngDemo -O3 -fast -L/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux5E/lib64/
```

Edit 2016-01-04 19:42 GMT:

Responding to comments

@High Performance Mark

You're right. At the end I get an error on the flag `ld: cannot find -leng`. However, this works when I ran on Matlab's example file.

@john elemans
See bolded file from `ls`

```
ls
archive            ElectricalSystem.f90    InputFile.f90               ParticleInCell.f90  StatisticalDistribution.f90
Calculus.f90       ElectrodeGeometry.f90   Iterative_Solvers.f90       pdetfxpd.m          StatisticalMechanics.f90
compile.tcsh       Emission.f90            makefile                    **PoissonSolver.f90**   Transformations.f90
Constants.f90      ExtraFunctions.f90      MonteCarloCollision.f90     PRNG.f90
CustomClasses.f90  GlobalVars.f90          NDPIC1D.f90                 RightHandSide.m
DataSubmit.job     Initialize_Poisson2D.m  NonElementaryFunctions.f90  Run_Poisson2D.m
```

Comment: Can you confirm that PoissonSolver.f90 exists at the correct location?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark see edits

Comment: @johnelemans see edits

Comment: That was my attempt to bold the file name, the file is just called `PoissonSolver.f90`. And a very similar series of commands works for the Matlab example. The only difference is the compile line, `${FC} fengdemo.f90 -I${matlabroot}/extern/include/ -L${matlabroot}/bin/glnxa64/ -leng -lmx -fpp -o FEngDemo -g -traceback -check -i8`

Comment: There isn't a `libeng` flag but I don't need it to compile using the Matlab example file.

Comment: I just kept fiddling with it and I got it to compile.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention. Use versions only when necessary.